# How far along a sequence do you have to go before the first $n$ decimal places are correct?

Tags: numerical-methods, power-series

Suppose we're given a sequence $s$ in the real line, converging to a limit $s_\infty$, and perhaps we want to know $s_\infty$ correct to the first $n$ decimal places. It would be handy to have an upper bound $U \in \mathbb{N}$ on how far along the sequence we have to go before the first $n$ decimal places are correct.

> **Question.** Are there any tools for obtaining such upper bounds?

For instance, define $e := \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{i!}.$ It turns out that

$$1+1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{24}+\frac{1}{120} = 2.71\dot{6}$$

gives the first two decimal places correct. But, how can we show this, and are there tools for finding such upper bounds for more general problems?

Answer (score 2):

There's not, like, a universal magic wand you can wave at a sequence and find out how quickly it converges. But we have theorems that tell us things about convergence in many cases.

For example, you could interpret the sum $$e = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac1{i!}$$ as a consequence of the Taylor series expansion of $e^x$ around $x=0$, evaluated at $x=1$, which has the more general form $$f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(i)}(a) (x-a)^i}{i!}.$$ Taylor's theorem also tells us (under some assumptions on $f(x)$ that $e^x$, being the nicest function possible, definitely satisfies) about the error term if we truncate this expansion: that there is some $\xi$ between $a$ and $x$ such that $$f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{f^{(i)}(a) (x-a)^i}{i!} + \frac{f^{(n+1)}(\xi) (x-a)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}.$$ Going back to the original sum, there is some $\xi \in [0,1]$ such that $$e = \sum_{i=0}^n \frac1{i!} + \frac{e^\xi}{(n+1)!}.$$ In particular, since $\xi \le 1$, the error is at most $\frac{e}{(n+1)!}$, so we have something like $\left\lfloor \log_{10} \frac{(n+1)!}{e} \right\rfloor$ correct digits. (I might be off by $1$, but you get the idea.) Stirling's formula tells us that this is on the order of $n \log_{10} n$ correct digits.

Comment: Is this really that useful though? You've found an upper bound on the number of correct digits of $e$, in terms of $e$ - so we need to already know $e$ in advance to know whether or not we've found $e$...

Comment: In terms of $e$, I guess, but $e$ doesn't play an important role in that approximation. We could just say that $e < 3$ and therefore the error is at most $\frac{3}{(n+1)!}$.

Comment: That's a good point, but how do we know $e<3$?

Comment: There are lots of elementary ways to get a constant bound on $e$ if we don't care how good that bound is. For example, by observing that $n! \ge 2^{n-1}$, we can say that $e = \frac1{0!} + \frac1{1!} + \frac1{2!} + \frac1{3!} + \frac1{4!} \dotsb \le 1 + 1 + \frac12 + \frac14 + \frac18 + \dotsb = 3$.

Comment: Ah, very clever.